# Programmatically manipulate GPX data

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geometry, coordinate-system, gpx

I need to do the following in Python

- open OSM & GPX files (I have packages for this)
- transform points from GPX (like stick a track to roads)
- calculate the results (distances, cumulative distances, etc.)

I need to do this repeatedly, so a Python script is much more preferred. Desktop software with plugins is not suitable. I'll prefer some Python & C modules than a quest of installing plugins. PostGIS may be an option too.

Shapely (Python package) seems to not be able to do this (it works only in 2D on a plane, and mentions it has no projections). I don't need 3D, but I have the input as lat&lon coordinates, and need to do geometric transformations (project a point on a polyline) and calculate distances in metres.

What modules should I use?

Comment: Maybe elaborate on which 3D functionality you need. It's not immediately clear.

Comment: Explained that in the last paragraph. The thing is that the input is lat&lon points, and the output should be metres. I can't see how Shapely does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- osgeo.ogr can read all these formats: [OGR Vector Formats](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_formats.html)
- osgeo.ogr and shapely support 3D:

  ```
  from osgeo import ogr
  point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint25D)
  point.AddPoint(5,4,4)
  point.GetZ()
  4.0

  from shapely.geometry import Point
  point1 = Point(5,4,4)
  point1.has_z
  True
  point1.z
  4.0
  ```
- you can change projections with osgeo.ogr: see [Projecting shapefile with transformation using OGR in python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19401/projecting-shapefile-with-transformation-using-ogr-in-python) and many, many other examples
- transform the geometries between ogr and shapely is easy:

  ```
  from shapely.wkb import loads
  point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint25D)
  point.AddPoint(5,4,4)
  point_shapely = loads(point.ExportToWkb())
  point_shapely.has_z
  True
  ```
- inverse

  ```
  point_ogr = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(point_shapely.wkb)
  print point_ogr.GetX(), point_ogr.GetY(), point_ogr.GetZ()
  5.0 4.0 0.0
  ```
- so you can use ogr or pyproj to change the projection of a shapely geometry, (see [Measuring distance in spherical Mercator vs zoned UTM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7293/measuring-distance-in-spherical-mercator-vs-zoned-utm) for example)
- and shapely or analytical geometry allows to project a point on a PoLyline (see [How to draw perpendicular lines in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59169/how-to-draw-perpendicular-lines-in-qgis/59196#59196), with PyQGIS, but it is similar with ogr)

As one example of the process, here are the results of the creation of geological cross-sections from 3D points  (from [Python: Using vector and raster layers in a geological perspective, without GIS software](http://www.portailsig.org/content/python-utilisation-des-couches-vectorielles-et-matricielles-dans-une-perspective-geologique-), in French, but the scripts and the figures are universal).

3D representation (distance between points):

[image]

cumulative distance (geological cross-section)

[image]

Comment: I'll try doing thsi. But I have tested the latest version of Shapely: Point(0, 0, 0).distance(Point(0, 0, 1)) == 0.0 They explicitly say the z-value is not used in calculations.

Comment: yes but you can use ogr for that or the module  shapely.affinity allowing 3D affine transformations